# codeigniter routes remove the controller name

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my site i have many controllers like
1. admin
2. pages
3. hotels ...

My url is `http://localhost/pages/page/about` ---> I want it to be as `http://sitename/page/about`

`http://localhost/admin/admin`---> I want it to be as `http://sitename/admin`

`http://localhost/hotels/display/samplehotel`---> I want it to be as `http://sitename/display/samplehotel`

in my routes file i write as 
`$route['pages'] = "pages/$1";` [Pages is my controller name].

But it shows an error. How to write this. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing

```
$route['page/about'] = 'controler_name/method_name';
```

if you method takes input you can write

```
$route['page/(:any)'] = 'controler_name/method_name/$1';
```

Comment: I have many number of dynamic pages like (about, rtest, test2 ...). Shall i manually write this for each? The page names are controlled by backend?

Comment: Yes, I think you will have to write it for each pages.

Answer (score 3):

```
$route['page/(:any)'] = 'pages/page/$1';
```

Or just:

```
$route['page/about'] = 'pages/page/about';
```

CodeIgniter URI routing documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

For admin part, I think it is better to change the name of your function from `admin` to `index`, and you don't need to set a routing rule for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['page/(:any)'] = "pages/page/$1";
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/admin/$1";
$route['display/(:any)'] = "hotels/display/$1";
```